# Opening *.odt files using Qt

Tags: html, c++, xml, qt, odt

I'm writing a program and I have to write a code which opens *.odt files. My idea is to extract content.xml file from *.odt document, and set the text from this xml file to my QTextEdit object. I made first part of this operation. Now I've got a problem with setting xml text to QTextEdit. For example, I've got a QDomDocument object which contains this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" office:version="1.2">
  <office:automatic-styles>
    <style:style style:name="c0" style:family="text">
      <style:text-properties fo:font-family="Sans"/>
    </style:style>
    <style:style style:name="p1" style:family="paragraph">
      <style:paragraph-properties/>
    </style:style>
    <style:style style:name="c10" style:family="text">
      <style:text-properties fo:font-family="Sans" fo:font-size="14pt" style:text-underline-style="none" fo:color="#ff0004"/>
    </style:style>
    <style:style style:name="c8" style:family="text">
      <style:text-properties fo:font-family="Sans" fo:font-size="14pt" style:text-underline-style="solid"/>
    </style:style>
    <style:style style:name="c6" style:family="text">
      <style:text-properties fo:font-style="italic" fo:font-family="Sans" fo:font-size="14pt"/>
    </style:style>
    <style:style style:name="c4" style:family="text">
      <style:text-properties fo:font-weight="bold" fo:font-family="Sans" fo:font-size="14pt"/>
    </style:style>
  </office:automatic-styles>
  <office:body>
    <office:text>
      <text:p text:style-name="p1"><text:span text:style-name="c4">BOLD</text:span></text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="p1"><text:span text:style-name="c6">ITALIC</text:span></text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="p1"><text:span text:style-name="c8">UNDERLINED</text:span></text:p>
      <text:p text:style-name="p1"><text:span text:style-name="c10">RED TEXT</text:span></text:p>
    </office:text>
  </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

Now I want to set this QDomDocument text to QTextEdit. I tried to do this using this line:

```
editor->setHtml(doc.toString()); // editor is a QTextEdit object and doc is QDomDocument
```

Here's my problem. After this line I've got a plain text in my editor (without any formatting, color etc.). How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you expect? That QTextEdit knows how you want it colorized? But at least you can have better formatting... toString takes a parameter: Indentation.

Comment: By formatting I mean bold, underline etc.

Comment: You understand the difference between xml and html?

Comment: Not really ;/ I just want to convert xml to html.

Comment: Ok, let me tell you: Forget it. QTextEdit cannot show .odf files, or do you think Qt integrated the whole office in this class? XML is first an foremost data. How the data is presented depends on the interpreter. Load your xml into a browser and you get at best some default highlighting, which is only 'nice to have', but has nothing to do with the .odt document.

Comment: So how can I open *.odt files? Have You got any ideas?

Comment: You opened it. The code sample above clearly shows an opened .odt file. You can keep it in the QDomDocument. You can modify it. You can save the modifications, but it you want to show it... this can only a program, which knows how to interpret this special brand of xml. And these are the office programs: OpenOffice, Microsoft Office, etc.... Qt definitely cannot do this. WAY out of scope of this framework.

Comment: OpenOffice is open-source, so you should be able to extract the parser from it and integrate into a Qt application. However this is probably a _mountain_ of work...

Comment: Or Calligra (https://www.calligra.org), which is written in Qt and probably more modular than LibreOffice.

Comment: Why can't you simply use LibreOffice to do the job? You could integrate it with your application, if you wanted tighter integration, but basic integration is already there.